# How to find out which delimiter was last used by Scanner with multiple delimiters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Just skip to the question if you don't care about examples/backstories

## Story behind this

I'm currently trying to debug a piece of code so that I can fix any problems so I won't have to rewrite the whole thing later. Unfortunately, it prints out an eyesore so I'm trying to clean it up

## Examples

These examples already include the fix I tried, but I marked it out. Also, please note they're all canon with each other

#### The Main class (the one that prints out the debug info)

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(Foo.toString).useDelimiter("\\[|\\]|,]"); //I'm using the delimiters "[", "]", and ",", because they're used for the debug program to separate Objects/Arrays
        //My fix starts here
        String debugOutput = "Output: "
        do{
            try {
                foo = s.next();
                debugOutput = debugOutput + foo + "\n";
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ignore){
                bar = false;
            }
        } while (bar);
        //My fix ends here
        System.out.println(debugOutput); //Without a fix, the debugOutput would be debugInfo
    }
}
```

#### The Foo class that I'm debugging

```
class Foo{ //Class I'm trying to debug

    //The code I'm busy debugging (for a list of classes, see the output as I don't feel like typing it all out

    @Override
    public String toString() {return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);}
}
```

#### The output I'm getting without my "fix"

```
ExampleClass@123456[ExampleArray1=[ExampleString1="Example String 1",ExampleString2="Example String 2"],ExampleObject1@234567=[ExampleString3="Example String 3",ExampleString4="Example String 4"],ExampleString5="Example String 5"]
```

#### The output I'm looking for (doesn't have to be exactly the same)

```
ExampleClass@123456
    ExampleArray1=
        ExampleObject2="Example String1"
        ExampleObject3="Example String2"
    ExampleObject1@234567=
        ExampleString3="Example String 3"
        ExampleString4="Example String 4"
    ExampleString5="Example String 5"
```

## External libraries that I'm using

- org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder

## My question

Is there a way to find out what delimiter has last been used?

It doesn't have to be Scanner, and since this won't be in the final code, it doesn't matter how messy the solution is.
I realize this is a popular question to ask, but all the questions were looking for a more closed answer. I'm fine with changing a lot of what I've done so far.

Comment: Also, ideas are welcome in the comment section, as they could help potential answerers

Comment: are you trying to reinvent JSON? scanner isn't meant to be used this way, you're going to have a bad time. either read it and do a recursive descent, or just pass xml/json/filename of a serialized java object to begin with.

Comment: @Dmitry I have tried using JSON before, however I don't believe that it's able to handle non-primitives. So in a way, I kinda am, so that it can work to my needs

Comment: what non primitives are you using that can't be serialized/deserialized? Also your example is not complete, please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so we know what's happening.

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Okay, I will try to edit the question in an order that makes my question and my attempts easier to distinguish between. Thanks for being constructive (I'm not sarcastic, sorry if it sounds that way)

Comment: (0) posted code doesn't actually do `[],` as claimed (1) I don't think `Scanner` can tell you the delimiter found (2) my commons-lang3 (3.4) by default produces a different format than you show (particularly no quotemarks), which can't be correctly parsed using single characters and I think not any regexp (3) however my commons-lang3 _can_ produce _almost_ what you ask for using `ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE` (either explicit or defaulted) per the javadoc and since this is open source it should be easy to change further if you want

Comment: @dave (0), i did this on the spot, sorry, i fixed it (1) I did mention I'm not looking for a method in Scanner that does this (although id be happy if there was one) (2) Sorry, this is just a demonstration, my debug info has no strings in it, do i just assumed that a string would get quotes around it. Ill fix it ASAP (3) Okay ill try this.

Comment: Great question. I am looking for the same thing.